# MKMapView keeps zooming out when dequeued and re-queued on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview

I am building an application that has a UITableController with a custom UITableViewCell that contains a MKMapView with some text. I have the content displaying properly, but when the cell is dequeued or removed from view, once it reappears, the map has zoomed out ever so slightly, and it keeps zooming out the more and more you dequeue and re-queue. Can anyone help me out here? I have gone into the storyboard editor and have turned off all zooming and scrolling for the mapView, I am unsure why the view continues to zoom out.

`TableViewController.swift`:

```
....
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MapTableViewCell
    cell.mapView.delegate = self
    showRoute(routes: locationStructArray[indexPath.row].route, color: UIColor.green, mapView: cell.mapView)

    return cell
}

func showRoute(routes:[MKRoute], color: UIColor, mapView: MKMapView){
    for i in 0..<routes.count{
        plotPolyLine(route: routes[i], color: color, mapView: mapView)
    }
}

func plotPolyLine(route: MKRoute, color: UIColor, mapView: MKMapView){
    let poly = route.polyline
    let mypoly = MyColoredPolyline(points: poly.points(), count: poly.pointCount)
    mypoly.color = color
    mapView.add(mypoly)
    if mapView.overlays.count == 1 {
        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mypoly.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0), animated: false)
    }
    else {
        let polylineBoundingRect =  MKMapRectUnion(mapView.visibleMapRect, mypoly.boundingMapRect)
        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(polylineBoundingRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0), animated: false)
    }
}

extension TableViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let route: MyColoredPolyline = overlay as! MyColoredPolyline

        let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: route)
        pr.lineWidth = 3.0
        pr.strokeColor = route.color
        return pr
    }
}
```

**EDIT** GIF with suggestions added in: http://gph.is/2qAx6Ls

Answer (score 2):

```
cell.mapView.removeOverlays(cell.mapView.overlays)
```

I think it is because you forgot to remove old polylines from the same map view that you'll reuse:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = ...
  cell.mapView.delegate = self
  cell.mapView.removeOverlays(cell.mapView.overlays)
  showRoute(routes: locationStructArray[indexPath.row].route, color: UIColor.green, mapView: cell.mapView)
  return cell
}
```

What's better is to do it in `MapTableViewCell`'s [`prepareForReuse()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) method instead:

```
class MapTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  ...

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, it still zooms out, but his time only once? Meaning, the most a map view will zoom out is one time, and then if I keep dequeueing and re-queueing it will stay the same

Comment: Maybe you should share a .gif image or screenshot with us showing the issue.

Comment: added gif in the op